ApplicationInsights Web Proxy Configuration
My .NET Core web application is running on an on premise IIS. I want to track the application using ApplicationInsights.
After installation on premise I do not receive any events (working fine in dev) - I have a HTTP Proxy I could use but I can't figure out how to set this for ApplicationInsights().
In my Startup.cs
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

In my appsettings.Production.json
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "<connectionstring_from_the_azure_portal>"
  }

How can I set the proxy?

Added HTTP_PROXY / HTTPS_PROXY in Environment variables will be picked up by ApplicationInsights.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\your.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess">
            <environmentVariables>
                <environmentVariable name="HTTP_PROXY" value="http://proxyurl:1234" />
                <environmentVariable name="HTTPS_PROXY" value="http://proxyurl:1234" />
            </environmentVariables>
        </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>

